# Need to release IBOutlet object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have dilemma about Memory releasing IBOutlet object.Do anyone please suggest what to do when we create IBOutlet object without property, need to release it?? if need to release... why we are releasing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is YES.

The runtime connects the objects to `IBOutlet` using `[setValue:ForKey:]`. This function will find the private instance variables, retain the target and set it to the instance variable. Please visit here [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html) to know more.

I highly recommend you to read the article because many iOS framework accesses properties by Key-Value compliance (`[setValue:ForKey:]` or `[valueForKey:]`), instead of directly calling getters/setters/instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

`IBOutlet` does not change the ownership semantics of properties. If you do not use ARC you have to release retained objects as with any other property.

Comment: My question is that.. if m not going to give make property for that object... still need to release IBOutlet object release in block of dealloc??

Answer (score 1):

Just Set it to default, which is "Weak". Then you are fine with ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a private IBOutlet property, to make things clearer and more explicit. I always do this personally:

```
MyClassName.m

@interface MyClassName ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSObject *myPropertyNameForAnOutlet;
@end

@implementation MyClassName 
...
@end
```

Comment: Michael you are right.. but still has confustion about this. My question is that.. if m not going to give make property for that object... still need to release IBOutlet object release in block of dealloc??

Comment: Sorry, you're right, that's not enough of an answer. But, if you make it weak, and you are using ARC, you can be reassured it will be cleaned up properly without any extra effort from you. Just attach your UI to it and forget about it. If non ARC, then set it to nil in viewDidUnload (pre iOS 6) and release it in dealloc. I would go ARC and save effort if I were you.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of the possibility to tag private properties (in a class extension) with `IBOutlet`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is YES...

i was confused about that too, but try this:

open a xib file

onen assistant editor window and get the .h file code near your XIB IB file

chose an object in IB file (an object with no reference to any var)

ctrl click on it and chose: "new reference outlet" button

drag the line to your .h code file in the @interface{   } section

give a name to your new var ("aaa")

(note that no property "aaa" is created)

now Xcode has done all the magic for you, and...

in .m file you can find, in dealloc method:

```
- (void) dealloc {   
    [aaa release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

so... if apple release it, it seems that the default IBOutlet vars loaded via XIB file are retained...

**EDIT:**

here's the [point in apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW35):

Comment: Thanks meronix.. same confusion generated when i did the same approach you used..

Comment: Apple documentation says that if you take ownership(alloc,retain,copy)then you can release it.. why this object release apple in dealloc method

Comment: they say also that you are responsable of object loaded in a nib: "You should then either synthesize the corresponding accessor methods, or implement them according to the declaration, and (in iOS) release the corresponding variable in dealloc." read it in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8

Answer (score 1):

You are not the owner of that object. so no need to release IBOutlet object.If you are using @property (nonatomic, retain) on IBoutlet object then you must release that object in dealloc.

Take a look at [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)
**You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**

Answer (score 0):

You are not the owner of the object, therefore you do not release it.

You become the owner by retaining, copying or creating (init/alloc) an object. Only then you are you (one of the) owner(s) of the object, and need to release it when you are done with the object. Fore more info check
[Cocoa core competencies - Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)

I hope this explains why you do not have to release the object.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8   here thay say you need to releas it (in iOS)

Comment: Yes, and it also states "Prior to ARC, the rules for managing nib objects are different from those described above. How you manage the objects depends on the platform and on the memory model in use. Whichever platform you develop for, you should define outlets using the Objective-C declared properties feature.", so to make sure you get it right you should use it as a property.

Comment: Yes, i do agree and always prefer using property, but the "academic" question is: if we don't use property (with a declared retain or assign), which is the default used by Xcode? i guess that if it was assign and we try to release it, we get a crash for a zombie... but that doesn't happen... so the default behavior should be "retain"...   said that, of course it's better (and faster and easier) to use property and deallc with self.myProperty = nil;

Answer (score -1):

Even though you didn't set it as property, the property is refer to setter and getter methods. When you use an object you should always remember to release it. The property is unrelated with memory issue.